# Mocha Global tests and context documentation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am currently working on making "global" tests in mocha. Basically, these are rules that I want to run after every test that I write to ensure certain global behaviors, like cleaning up resources.

Currently, the best approach that I have involves using `beforeEach`/`afterEach` to programmatically fail tests if they do not comply to this behavior.

Example:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  // Set up some tracking stuff using sinon
});

afterEach(function() {
  if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
    return;
  }

  if (thisTestHasALeak(this.currentTest)) {
    this.test.error(new Error('This Test Has a leak'));
  }
});
```

This approach works, but there are some features that are lacking, and development on this is slow b/c there does not appear to be documentation on what exactly exists on the `this` object in a mocha test. The best documentation I could find was [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/HOW-TO:-Conditionally-fail-a-test-after-completion), and that was limited.

Is there any good documentation or resources to help me with my effort?

Comment: You could log `this` or use the debugger to inspect it. To log a pretty-printed `this`, write `console.log('this:', require('util').inspect(this));`.

Comment: that's how I've gotten this far :). They are some incredibly large objects on there, and it is hard to parse. I was hoping for some official documentation instead of just looking at properties.